# How to use avg function in mdx?

Tags: sql, mdx, business-intelligence

I have my `mdx` query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Dim Date].[Day Of Week].[Day Of Week].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20140730] : [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20150730] ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Cube]
  WHERE 
    [Dim Client].[Common Client UID].&[{some id}]
);
```

so i have my a weekday dim, which contain members as numbers from 1-7. Query find returns amount for each weekday, which is summed up, but i want to find out an average, so somehow i need to find out how many items was summed to give me  [Measures].[Amount] result. I have tryed with separate member function which didnt worked.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Avg] AS
    Avg(  
      ( [Dim Date].[Day Of Week].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].[Amount] )
   )
```

Avg return exectly the same value. How do i do such a request in mdx?

Comment: `average` is a number, which for a column will be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you an average *over* 1 member:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Avg] AS
    Avg(  
      ( [Dim Date].[Day Of Week].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].[Amount] )
   )
```

That is because `CURRENTMEMBER` is returning 1 member.

If you want an average over several members than you need to supply a *set* as the first argument for the `Avg` function. Here is an example:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Daily Avg] AS
    Avg(  
      Descedants(
         [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER
        ,[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
    ,[Measures].[Amount] 
   )
```

Although I suspect something like the follwoing should work in your context:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Avg] AS 
    Avg
    (
      (EXISTING 
        [Dim Date].[Date Int].MEMBERS)
     ,[Measures].[Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Amount]
     ,[Measures].[Avg]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Dim Date].[Day Of Week].[Day Of Week].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20140730] : [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20150730] ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Cube]
  WHERE 
    [Dim Client].[Common Client UID].&[{some id}]
);
```